# @OneToOne Relationship on Spring mcv

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm tired of trying things and I don't have any results. My user has One country and the country has many user. The problem is when I make a new user.
I don't have any idea where is the problem.

I have this User Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usuarios")
public class Usuario {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nombre", nullable=false)
    private String nombre;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_pais")
    private Pais pais;

    /* Getters & Setters */
    ....
}
```

The Country Bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="paises")
public class Pais {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="pais")
    private Set<Usuario> usuarios;

    /* Getters & Setters */

}
```

The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario")
public class UsuariosController {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public RedirectView store(Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioService.store(usuario);      
        return new RedirectView("../usuario");
    }
    @ModelAttribute("usuario")
    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return new Usuario();
    }   
}
```

The Service:

```
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImplement implements UsuarioService{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO;

    public void store(final Usuario usuario) {
        usuarioDAO.store(usuario);
    }
}
```

The DAO:

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioHibernateDAO implements UsuarioDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void store(final Usuario usuario) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(usuario);
    }
}
```

**The form:**

```
<form:form action="../usuario" method="POST" commandName="usuario">

    <!-- nombre -->
    <form:input path="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" />

    <!-- pais -->

    <form:select path="pais" class="form-control">
        <form:option value="1">España</form:option>
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" />
</form:form>
```

And I obtain this:

```
Estado HTTP 400 -

type Informe de estado

mensaje

descripción El requerimiento enviado por el cliente era sintácticamente incorrecto.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.20
```

Comment: Whats your problem ?  can u explain in english ?

Comment: My problem is when I try to create a new user . Not working relationship with the country and gives me an error 400 in apache. If I remove the relationship and the attribute country , it works correctly .

Comment: Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type com.lookautonomos.domain.Pais for property pais; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.lookautonomos.domain.Pais] for property pais: no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

I had a same Problem with these,you can set object manually by id.I hope it will solve your problem.

Try this!

```
usuario.setPais(paisService.getPaisById(request.getParameter("pais")));
```